# How to add session and add access token to login in node

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, session, authentication

I have a login api as follows :

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res){

email = req.body.email;
password = req.body.password;
if(email && password )
{
console.log(email); //displays the email in the terminal
console.log(password); //displays the password in the terminal
var status = []; //array to output json

//connection.connect(); //mysql connection

connection.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE email =? and password = ?',[email,password], function (error, rows, fields) {

if(rows.length == 1)
{
  passport.serializeUser(function(res, done) {
                    done(null,res);
                });

                passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
                    done(null,res);

                });

status.push({username: rows[0].username});
username = rows[0].username;

console.log('sucessful login');
res.end('"status:"\n'+JSON.stringify(status)); //output as JSON
}

if(rows.length == 0)
{

connection.query('select * from temp_users where email = ? and password = ?',[email,password],function(error,rows,fields)
{
status = '';
if(rows.length == 1)
{
status = 'pending';
//res.end('Your Account needs to be verified');
res.end('"status:"'+JSON.stringify(status));
console.log('Your Account needs to be verified.');
}
else
{
status = 'error';
res.end('"status:"'+JSON.stringify(status));
//res.end('no such user.Please create an account');
console.log('no such user.Please create an account');
}
}
);
}


});
}
});
```

Now what i would like to do is to add a session for every user that logs in and make that session expire after some time.I would also like to have an access token to be inserted to my database once the user logs in.
Any help?

Comment: [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) + [express-mysql-session](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-mysql-session)

Answer (score 0):

This example does exactly what you are looking for.

[node.js express mysql passport](http://www.crashcoder.com/nodejs-user-autentication-and-session-storage-using-express-mysql-passport/)